# System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: data source Parameter name: keyword'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, progress

I get the above error when trying to run a repository from github
https://github.com/aliakseiherman/eixample

The application was build to use ProgressSql - how do I change it to use SQLSERVER ?

Is it possible to to change/switch from ProgresSql to SQLSERVER when an application was bui;d using ProgressSql ?

Would appreciate help, let me know if I must post any suitable code

Comment: When you say "ProgressSql" are you referring to the OpenEdge database?  Posting suitable code is always helpful.

Comment: Please check the document to modify your appSettings.json and `options.UseSqlServer`:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio